# When Deploying a Laravel project on Heroku, I got errors

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I am new to heroku and got these errors when I tried to deploy my Laravel app.
I added web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ on the procfile too.

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        Deprecation Notice: Return type ofIlluminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1231
remote:        Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1242
remote:        Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1254
remote:        Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1267
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1231
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1242
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1254
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1267
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 141
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 152
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 164
remote:        PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 175
remote:        PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1277
remote:        Stack trace:
remote:        #0 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
remote:        #1 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')
remote:        #2 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
remote:        #3 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(109): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
remote:        #4 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130): collect()
remote:        #5 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
remote:        #6 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
remote:        #7 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
remote:        #8 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
remote:        #9 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(219): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
remote:        #10 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(320): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
remote:        #11 /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
remote:        #12 /tmp/build_275de9ef/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
remote:        #13 {main} in /tmp/build_275de9ef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 11
remote:        Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
remote:  !     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !     
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !     
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to qutesapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/qutesapp.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/qutesapp.git'
```

But, this app is working well on my local machine. I think it is a problem related to composer update... Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using and what version of Laravel?

Comment: @lagbox PHP version is 7.4.30 and Laravel is 6.20.44 and as I said, it is working on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, this is due to attempting to run Laravel 7 (or earlier) under PHP 8.1. try to change  PHP versions

Comment: Can you check composer.json file require PHP and laravel/framework version

Comment: "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|8.1.8",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.20.26",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },

Comment: Version  - 6 (LTS) 
PHP      - 7.2 - 8.0
1.Wrong PHP version are mentioned  "php": "^7.4|8.1.8"
2.Check server php version . And server php version must 7.2 - 8.0 this range 
3.https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#support-policy

Comment: when I do git push Heroku master. Preparing platform package installation...
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        - php (8.1.8)
remote:        - apache (2.4.54)
remote:        - composer (2.3.9)
remote:        - nginx (1.22.0). How can I change the server php version?

Comment: Your server PHP version is 8.1.8; that's the issue .. Kindly downgrade your PHP version

Comment: I'm googling it but cannot find how to do that. So, could you tell me how to downgrade the server's PHP version, please?

Comment: Are you configuring apache or nginx  ??

Comment: I am doing apache

Comment: just refer to this link .. am not sure how effectively it's working or not
https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04